# Xamarin UITableView Row Expand on Row Select - Possible iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am researching Xamarin to possibly move current projects over to and have a C# standard. The following is specifically for iOS. 
One important requirement currently is as follows:

- Set a datasource of a Table or List
- Upon selecting a list item, that row will expand or collapse showing its relative data
- Each item in the list has a different layout

I have found that the above steps may be possibly with a table view, however, it is unclear if it is possible to expand the rows. I have found this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Z_kDWDLcSo) demonstrating similar functionality to what is required but this is in Objective C but I am currently not familiar with this language and unsure what the limitations of xamarin are compared to objective C.

Should I use RowSelected? If so, is there an example of adjusting the height based the data?

Other examples of the requirements are

- [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqoVLuTHjC4)
- [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMs7K7ZHcWw)
- **This one** **[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6n-c5MqMSuI)** is my favourite

In short, show a row with a summary label, click rows, show more data for that row. Any simple rough example would be really helpful.

I am open to expanding the height or having a row related to the one clicked on that shows and hides

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You likely have the answer to this, but it is still worth posting a reply in case other people have similar questions.

Lets start with: "Set a datasource of a Table or List."

This is of course possible in Forms, or alternatively in individual iOS and Android builds. In iOS for example you actually create a source class for your table view that allows you to iterate through data, access the row select methods, and do a whole array of useful tinkering.

"Upon selecting a list item, that row will expand or collapse showing its relative data."

Yes this is entirely possible and their are a few ways that you can implement it, you can utilise the row selected method and simply expand the height of the table view to show hidden content or alternatively you can create a sub cell, almost like an accordion effect. There are plenty of guides on this online.

Lastly "Each item in the list has a different layout"

This can be done when iterating through your source when creating the tables cells, and will allow you to change the content based on some sort of tag/flag that is part of your data objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tableviews sections and rows. When a sections is touched, it expanses/collapses to show/hide the rows. Use a List which keeps track of whether a section is expanded or not.. Here's an example of the TableViewSource. I think the code is pretty self explanatory.

```
public class MyTableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    string SectionIndentifer = "mySection";
    string CellIndentifer = "myCell";

    public List<MyItem> vList { get; set; }
    List<bool> expandStatusList; // Maintain a list which keeps track if a section is expanded or not

    public MeasurementsDetailsTableSource (List<MyItem> vList)
    {
        this.vList = vList;
        expandStatusList = new List<bool> ();

        for (int i = 0; i < vList.Count; i++) {
            expandStatusList.Add (false); // Initially, no section are expanded
        } 
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
    {
        return vList.Count;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        if (!expandStatusList [(int)section])
            return 0; // Returning 0 to hide all the rows of the section, there by collapsing the section.
        return vList [(int)section].subItems.Count; 
    }

    public override UIView GetViewForHeader (UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (SectionIndentifer);
        if (cell == null) {
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, SectionIndentifer);
        }
        ...
        // Settings up a click event to section to expand the section..

        var gesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer ();
        gesture.AddTarget (() => ParentClick (gesture));
        cell.AddGestureRecognizer (gesture);

        cell.Tag = section; // This is needed to indentify the section clicked..

        return cell;
     }

     public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
     {
         UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (CellIndentifer);
         if (cell == null) {
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIndentifer);
         }
         ...
         return cell;
     }

     public void ParentClick (UITapGestureRecognizer gesture)
     {

         NSIndexPath indexPath = NSIndexPath.FromRowSection (0, gesture.View.Tag);
         if (indexPath.Row == 0) {
             if (vList [indexPath.Section].mValues.Count != 0) {
                 bool expandStatus = expandStatusList [indexPath.Section];
                 for (int i = 0; i < vList.Count; i++) {
                     if (indexPath.Section == i) {
                         expandStatusList [i] = !expandStatus;
                     }
                 }
                 tableView.ReloadSections (NSIndexSet.FromIndex (gesture.View.Tag), UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic);
                 tableView.ReloadData ();
                 return;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```